Ubuntu 22.04 notification popup styling is off
I recently upgraded ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04. not the notification popup styling is off. I have attached a screenshot of this here,
this is how it responds to the command notify-send "Hello world"


did you try changing your gtk theme?
this might be bad advice, but perhaps do sudo apt install lxappearance
then run lxappearance and try setting different themes from there
